# QuickBlox How to check QBChat/didDisconnect to force the user to login again?

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, quickblox

I want to check QBChat/didDisconnect in my code because i want to force the user to log in again to the app when QBChat/didDisconnect. I am already using the following method but sometimes it got ERROR like the following:

> QBChat/didDisconnect, error: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo=0x9ca1260 {NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer} ;

```
- (void)sendPresence{
    // presence in QuickBlox Chat
    [[QBChat instance] sendPresence];
    // presence in QuickBlox
    [QBUsers userWithExternalID:1 delegate:nil];
}
```

By the way, after creating a chat room with "[[QBChat instance] createOrJoinRoomWithName:@"name" membersOnly:NO persistent:YES];", it takes time to work out the following method. And Sometimes, that method is not called properly.

```
- (void)chatRoomDidEnter:(QBChatRoom *)room{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **QBChatDelegate's** method

```
-(void)chatDidFailWithError:(int)code
{
}
```

If it was manual logout - code will be equal to 0

Comment: How to make keep QBChat login as long as the app is running? To make sure no need to login again.

Comment: "QBChat/didDisconnect, error: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo=0x10e58040 {NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}". This ERROR is got in the middle of chat and "the user is needed to log in again" message is shown. I am sure that sendPresence method is working as fine but why this error come out.

Comment: Your app can be disconnected form chat by many reasons. So, it's normal situation to handle reconnect.

You can do silent reconnect (just save in app user's credentials and do reconnect with them) - not to show Login screen again and again